# Adding forgot-password feature to Django 2.1 admin site

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I read the documentation but whatever don't understand what is the best way to add the forgot-password feature to **Django 2.1** admin site, help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do add `django.contrib.auth.urls` to your project urls, these functionality will be automatically imported(including login, logout, password change functionality). Like this:

```
path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Or if you want to exclusively add the reset password functionality, then add them from `django.contrib.auth.views`. Like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```